# Using a comma in a 'double' with Math Round

Tags: c#, wpf, string, double

I would like to display my calculated amount with a `,` and the **last two decimal places** ex. `1000.00` = `1,000.00`. I have tried the coding below, and it works, but It removes my two decimal places when I round it at the end.

```
lblTotalInclVatAmount.Content = "R " + Math.Round((double + double),2).ToString("N0");
```

It's sounds simple enough. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: you probably need to use `ToString("N2")`?

Comment: @Bolu - That worked, thank you! :D

Comment: " I have tried the coding below, and it works" - not *that* code, it doesn't. What do you expect `double + double` to do, given that `double` is a keyword?

Comment: I just added double to show the type of values that I was calculating. It actually looks like this with the new working code:  `lblTotalInclVatAmount.Content = "R " + Math.Round((Vat + totalExVat),2).ToString("N2");` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The precision specifier indicates the desired number of digits after the decimal point.

As such you are looking for `ToString("N2")` instead.

You can see more information from: [The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#NFormatString)

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 1000;
string s = d.ToString("N");
```

s is now 1,000.00

Comment: This works thanks @Mick3y, but Bolu already gave me a correct answer as well. If he doesn't post the answer, I will give you the correct answer. ;)